# Java Collections Optimization

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a java application that connects to database to fetch some records, processes each records and updates record back to the db table.

Following is my db schema (with sample data):

```
Table A: Requests

| REQUESTID |    STATUS | 
-------------------------
|  1        |    PENDING|
|  2        |    PENDING|

Table B: RequestDetails


| DETAILID | REQUESTID   | STATUS  | USERID |
---------------------------------------------
|  1       |    1        | PENDING | RA1234 |
|  2       |    1        | PENDING | YA7266 |
|  3       |    2        | PENDING | KAJ373 |
```

Following is my requirement:

1) Fetch Request along with pending status along with request data from both tables
   I'm using below query for this:

```
SELECT Requests.REQUEST_ID as "RequestID",RequestDetails.USERID as "UserID",RequestDetails.DETAILID as "DetailID" 
FROM Requests Requests
JOIN RequestDetails RequestDetails
ON (Requests.REQUESTID=RequestDetails.REQUESTID AND Requests.REQUEST_STATUS='PENDING' AND RequestDetails.STATUS='PENDING')
```

2) I'm using a `HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String,String>>`  to store all the values

3) Iterate over each request and get details `List<HashMap<String,String>>`
   Perform action for each detail record and update status

4) After all detail records are processed for a request, update status of the request on requests table

The end state should be something like this:

```
    Table A: Requests

    | REQUESTID |    STATUS | 
    -------------------------
    |  1        |    PENDING|
    |  2        |    PENDING|

    Table B: RequestDetails


    | DETAILID | REQUESTID   | STATUS  | USERID |
    ---------------------------------------------
    |  1       |    1        | PENDING | RA1234 |
    |  2       |    1        | PENDING | YA7266 |
    |  3       |    2        | PENDING | KAJ373 |
```

My question is: the collection I'm using is quite complex (`"HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String,String>>"`). Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Thank you,
Sash

Comment: what do you mean, Hashmap is complex

Comment: @Vaibs I have just updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, why don't you use proper ORM? that should make life easier..

Comment: @BagusTesa I'm unable to do that because of project limitations. I can only use code java classes.

Comment: And why don't you define a Request class, having a Set<RequestDetails>, instead of storing everything into maps?

Comment: I see no difference between your "before" and "after" tables.

Comment: And why have the collection at all? Just iterate over the `ResultSet`and process each row directly,

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use class something like,

```
Class RequestDetails{
int detailId;
int statusId;
String status;
String userId;
}
```

instead of map `HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String,String>>` you should use `HashMap<String, RequestDetails>`That has advantages like, code simplicity and also when you working with huge data and you need to modify string it is always better to avoid using String data-type as it is immutable and decrease your performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @darshan, adding a class will reduce performance, won't it? And i will not modify any data, will just iterate. Thanks

Comment: Hi @PruthviRaj, as I mentioned using your class object is batter than using String object to store data, reasons: 1. It is a widely used practice so your code is more standard and readable for others too. 2. Using defined class over String is good idea but you should check performance with both techniques as it depends on volume of your data. So check for both option and use whichever suits your need more, I will advise to go with User Defined class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Above all that and what Darshan suggested, you must override the hashCode and equals method too, the reason is its the basic contract while dealing with HashMap  and it will also increase the performance too.